# Image doesn't display using readfile / file_get_contents

Tags: php, header, types, file-get-contents

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.(gif|jpe?g)$/',$row['filename'],$matches) &&
    is_readable($row['filepath'].$row['filename'])){    
  echo header('Content-Type: image/'.$matches[1]);    
  echo header('Content-Length: '.filesize($row['filepath'].$row['filename']));    
  echo file_get_contents($row['filepath'].$row['filename']);
} else {
  echo 'cant serve image: '.$row['filename'];
}
```

When I try to place the `header('Content-Type': image/jpeg)` for example, It only displays a blank page and the current url.

Im trying to display an image to replace my `<img>` tags.

filepath contains the physical path for the directory of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it'll solve the whole problem, but you should not use `echo` on the return value of the [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function : to send a header, just use the `header` function, and don't echo anything :

```
header('Content-Type: image/'.$matches[1]);
```

An invalid image *(ie, Firefox displays its URL instead of its content)* is often caused by invalid output before / after the image date -- make sure you don't have anything sent to the browser other than the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `echo header`, just `header`.